# Trying to print primes between n1 and n2, why am I not getting an output here?

Tags: shell-script

```
echo A program to print primes between 2 numbers
read -p "Enter starting number of range: " n1
read -p "Enter ending number of range: " n2
echo ""
if [ $n1 -le $n2 ]
then
    while [ $n1 -le $n2 ]
    do
        d=2
        while [ $d -lt $n1 ]
        do
            if [ $((n1%d)) -eq 0 ]
            then
                break
            fi
        if [ $d -eq $n1 ]
        then
            echo Prime: $d
        fi
        d=$((d+1))
        done
    n1=$((n1+1))
    done
else
    echo First number must be smaller than second number
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) ask a question, ii) tell us what operating system you are using, iii) tell us what shell you are using and iv) tell us how you are launching the script and what values you are entering. Next, the first step when debugging is to add print (`echo`) statements to see what your variables have. Do this and report back what you find. The problem should be obvious as soon as you start printing out the various values, at least you should be able to see where it happens.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @waltinator how would that have helped here? There is no serious syntax issue. The only "problem" is a few unquoted variables, but that wouldn't be an issue as long as the user only entered numbers anyway. So using shellcheck would not have helped in any way here.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for the tip, it'll be helpful in the future but I rarely make syntax mistakes and it's usually the first and easiest thing to check. The problem was in the loop logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you indented the program correctly the error would be more obvious.

The code

```
        if [ $d -eq $n1 ]
        then
            echo Prime: $d
        fi
```

is inside the `while [ $d -lt $n1 ]` loop, and so is never executed as the `d=$((d+1))` is at the very end of that loop.

Comment: Moved the stated line outside of the loop, that did it, thank you. For some reason I did not think break would take me out of the loop, just out of the if statement.